# うれしい(ureshii) Vs たのしい(tanoshii)

Tags: word-choice, i-adjectives

When exactly do we use うれしい(ureshii) and たのしい(tanoshii)
Ureshii - glad , pleasant
Tanoshii - happy

Ureshii is when you see someone being happy
Is ureshii also with event already happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ureshii* means "happy". As in, "I'm **happy** I won the lottery." Or in a different nuance, *ureshii taiken*, a "**grateful** experience", one you're happy to have had.
*Tanoshii* means "fun". "That party was **fun**."  Or, "I like to hang with **fun** people."